# How To Fix “The Debugger you selected cannot be started” (2)

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, vsjitdebugger

This question is a duplicate of another question with the same name, but with a different context and none of those suggestions worked for me.

I have a few processes which I start with a "-debug" command line argument which instructs those processes to invoke `Debugger.Launch()`

That used to work great, and I could debug those processes inside visual studio and step through the code, but since I installed Visual Studio 2017, it deteriorated a bit.

This is what happens now:

1. I start the process with the additional **-debug** command line argument.
2. The process invokes `Debugger.Launch()`
3. I see this window:

   [image]
4. I select the last option **Visual Studio 2017**
5. Then I get this:

   [image]
6. I click "Yes" and then I'm back at step number 3, now repeat 3 to 6 indefinitely. :-)

I'm not sure why, but I can no longer use Visual Studio 2017 to debug my projects using this method, and this was working a day or so ago, I just had to go through the iteration twice, but Visual Studio 2017 did eventually start up.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Help > Send Feedback > Report a problem.  Type "just-in-time debugger" in the search box.  Second hit is a match.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, are you referring to the 2nd item "Unacceptable load time"? I will do the recording and send the feedback.

Comment: That wasn't the one I saw.  Well, doesn't matter, sucks when they spin-off testing to their valued customers, let them have it.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out all I needed to do was make sure I am running the initial process or script as administrator.

[image]